# how time complexity O(n) works

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

what is the time complexity of 3k + 1

If I were not wrong time complexity of this equation is O(n)
3k + 1 -> 3x

-> O(n)

How the complexity O(n). Please explain.

Comment: can you please clarify your question a bit? There also seems to be problem with end lines

Comment: @ShihabShahriar I updated the question

Comment: The question is vague

Comment: @AjayGaur  3k + 1 complexity of this operation?

Comment: This looks like can be solved with a good read into the wikipedia page or some other tutorial resource.

Comment: Hope someone is waiting to provide my answer.

Answer (score 0):

3n + 1 =  3n :O(n)

let, if  n = 5 then  3*5 (3*3*3*3*3) (5 operations here)

that is linear complexity